# css or javascript dynamic positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to set div elements without overlapping and also like this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3paFX/)

is there any way can I do it in css or javascript?
in this code I actually used margin a lot. I think there better way doing this. Could you help me.

```
<div class='container'>
        <div class='work1 round'></div>
        <div class='work2 round'></div>
        <div class='work3 round'></div>
        <div class='work4 round'></div>
        <div class='work5 round'></div>
        <div class='work6 round'></div>
        <div class='work7 round'></div>
</div>

.container {
    width: 620px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,1);
}

.round {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.work1 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 115px 0 0 270px;
    position: absolute;
}
.work2 {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 65px 0 0 140px;
    position: absolute;
}
.work3 {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 65px 0 0 80px;
    position: absolute;
}

.work4 {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 165px 0 0 193px;
    position: absolute;
}

.work5 {
    width: 77px;
    height: 77px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 95px 0 0 213px;
    position: absolute;
}

.work6 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 148px 0 0 213px;
    position: absolute;
}

.work7 {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 68px 0 0 213px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: You can give the elements `top` and `left` properties to set their absolute position... It is probably better than using margin for this purpose.

Comment: still the same problem I have to put every single 'div' element.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? 

If you just want to position them one next to other, without overlapping, remove the margins and `position: absolute` and perhaps give them all `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a random generator then try this css -

```
.container {
width: 620px;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: rgba(200,200,200,1);
}

.round {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.work {
    background: #ddd;
    position: absolute;
}
```

with this JS -

```
var checkOverLap = function(circles, mTop, mLeft, radius){
    var x = mLeft + radius;
    var y = mTop + radius;
    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        var distance = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - circles[i].x, 2) + Math.pow(y - circles[i].y, 2)));
        if (distance < (radius + circles[i].radius)){
            //overlapped
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


$(function(){
    var cont = $(".container");
    cont.empty();
    var circles = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var div = $("<div>").addClass("work round");
        var w = Math.floor((Math.random() * cont.width()) + 1) / 5;
        var h = Math.floor((Math.random() * cont.height()) + 1) / 5;
        var mTop = Math.floor((Math.random() * (cont.height() - h)) + 1);
        var mLeft = Math.floor((Math.random() * (cont.width() - w)) + 1);
        var radius = w > h ? h/2 : w/2;
        if(checkOverLap(circles, mTop, mLeft, radius)){
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        $(div).css({
            width: w > h ? h : w,
            height: w > h ? h : w,
            marginTop: mTop,
            marginLeft: mLeft,
        });
        circles[circles.length] = {x:mLeft + radius, y:mTop + radius, radius: radius};
        cont.append(div);
    }
});
```

you may randomise more if you like. Here is the fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/3paFX/5/

Have fun!!!